# Selected Template switching with select not working - model going undefined

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Using a modified version of [Knockout.js wizard validation on each step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709285/knockout-js-wizard-validation-on-each-step) I plan to have a similar step-by-step wizard.

On the PaymentModel view-model step it has two child view-models (payment1Model and payment2Model), the child view-model that is displayed will be dependent on the selectedPaymentOption (option1 or option2).

**I switch between selected view models with the following code on the PaymentModel**

```
self.selectedPaymentOption.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(typeof newValue == "undefined")
        return;

    var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options(), function (item) {
        return item.name() == newValue;
    }, this);

    self.selectedTemplate(found.template);
    self.selectedModel(found.model());
},self);
```

I can switch between the templates the first time OK, but when switching back I am getting a null reference error and binding fails below.

[image: binding fails]

I suspect it is to do with setting the `selectedTemplate` before the `selectedModel` (or vice versa), and one attempting to bind without the other (chicken and egg situation) since the template uses `<div data-bind="template: { name: selectedTemplate, data: selectedModel }"></div>`.

Is there any way to defer updates until both have been selectedTemplate and selectedModel have been updated, or is there a better way to tackle this issue?

**[My fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/8PVwn/10/) and code below:**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'currentTmpl', data: currentStep }"></div> 

<button data-bind="click: goPrevious, visible: canGoPrevious">Previous</button>
<button data-bind="click: goNext, visible: canGoNext, enable: modelIsValid">Next</button>

<script id="payment1Tmpl" type="text/html">
    <p>payment option 1</p>
    <input id="details1" type="text" data-bind="value: details1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /> 
    <select id="expiresMonth" data-bind="options: expiresMonthOptions, value: expiresMonth" />
    <select id="expiresYear" data-bind="options: expiresYearOptions, value: expiresYear" />        
</script>

<script id="payment2Tmpl" type="text/html">
    <p>payment option 2</p>
    <input id="details2" type="text" data-bind="value: details2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /> 
</script>

<script id="currentTmpl" type="text/html">
    <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate, data: model }"></div> 
</script>

<script id="nameTmpl" type="text/html">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Name</legend>
        <p>
            <label for"FirstName">First Name</label>
            <input id="FirstName" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
            <p data-bind="validationMessage: firstName"></p>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</script>

<script id="paymentTmpl" type="text/html">
    <fieldset>  
        <p>
            <label for"someOtherDetail">Some other detail</label>
            <input id="someOtherDetail" type="text" data-bind="value: someOtherDetail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
        <select data-bind="options: paymentOptions, value: selectedPaymentOption"></select>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: selectedTemplate, data: selectedModel }"></div> 
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</script>

<script id="confirmTmpl" type="text/html">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Name</legend>
        <b><span data-bind="text:NameModel.firstName"></span></b>
        <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <button data-bind="click: confirm">Confirm</button>
</script>


ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'error'
});

function TemplatePage(id, name, template, model) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.template = template;
    self.model = ko.observable(model);

    self.getTemplate = function () {
        return self.template;
    };
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.nameModel = ko.observable(new NameModel());
    self.paymentModel = ko.observable(new PaymentModel());

    var confirmModel = {
        NameModel: self.nameModel(),
        PaymentModel: self.paymentModel() 
    };

    self.stepModels = ko.observableArray([
        new TemplatePage(1, "Step1", "nameTmpl", self.nameModel()),
        new TemplatePage(2, "Step2", "paymentTmpl", self.paymentModel()),
        new TemplatePage(3, "Confirmation", "confirmTmpl", confirmModel)
    ]);

    self.currentStep = ko.observable(self.stepModels()[0]);

    self.currentIndex = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.stepModels.indexOf(self.currentStep());
    });

    self.getTemplate = function (data) {
        return self.currentStep().template();
    };

    self.canGoNext = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.currentIndex() < (self.stepModels().length - 1));
    });

    self.modelIsValid = ko.computed(function () {
        if (typeof(self.currentStep().model().isValid) != "undefined") { 
            return self.currentStep().model().isValid();
        }
        else
            return true;
    });

    self.goNext = function () {
        if (self.currentIndex() < self.stepModels().length - 1) {
            var count = self.currentIndex() + 1;
            console.log(count);
            self.currentStep(self.stepModels()[count]);
        }
    };

    self.canGoPrevious = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.currentIndex() > 0;
    });

    self.goPrevious = function () {
        if (self.currentIndex() > 0) {
            var count = self.currentIndex() - 1;
            console.log(count);
            self.currentStep(self.stepModels()[count]);
        }
    };
}

Payment1Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.details1 = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    self.expiresMonthOptions = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
    self.expiresYearOptions = ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"];

    self.expiresMonth = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    self.expiresYear  = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    ko.validation.group(self);
}

Payment2Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.details2 = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    ko.validation.group(self);
}


NameModel = function(model) {
    var self = this;

    //Observables
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    ko.validation.group(self);

    return self;
};

var PaymentModel=function() {
    var self = this;

    self.payment1Model = ko.observable(new Payment1Model());
    self.payment2Model = ko.observable(new Payment2Model());

    self.someOtherDetail = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    self.options = ko.observableArray([
        new TemplatePage(1, "Payment1", "payment1Tmpl", self.payment1Model()),
        new TemplatePage(1, "Payment2", "payment2Tmpl", self.payment2Model()),
    ]);

    var optionNames = [];
    for(var i=0; i<self.options().length; i++)
    {
        optionNames.push(self.options()[i].name);
    }

    self.paymentOptions = optionNames;

    self.selectedPaymentOption = ko.observable(optionNames[0]);
    self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
    self.selectedModel = ko.observable();

    self.selectedPaymentOption.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if(typeof newValue == "undefined")
            return;

        var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options(), function (item) {
            return item.name() == newValue;
        }, this);

        self.selectedTemplate(found.template);
        self.selectedModel(found.model());
    },self);

    ko.validation.group(self);

    self.isParentAndChildValid = function () {
        if (typeof self.selectedModel() == "undefined")
            return false;
        return self.isValid() && self.selectedModel().isValid();
    };

    return {
        someOtherDetail: self.someOtherDetail,
        selectedPaymentOption: self.selectedPaymentOption,
        paymentOptions: self.paymentOptions,
        selectedTemplate: self.selectedTemplate,
        selectedModel: self.selectedModel,
        isValid: self.isParentAndChildValid
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/8PVwn/14/) working solution. Now it works without any errors.
What you need to do is to stop using next to separated variables:

```
self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
self.selectedModel = ko.observable();
```

Instead you've use one another variable that will hold selected option from options array:

```
 self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable(self.options()[0]);
```

Every time you change your choice of payment, you find selected option in options array. Just put it into a new variable self.selectedTemplate:

```
var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options(), function (item) {
    return item.name() == newValue;
}, this);
self.selectedTemplate(found);
```

Change HTML accordingly:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: selectedTemplate().template, data: selectedTemplate().model() }"></div>
```

**(EDIT)** Change all instances of selectedTemplate and selectedModel with new selectedTemplate().template and selectedTemplate().model()

Comment: many thanks +1 and ready to award, just a quick question - why when I change the method-payment from select to a radio button, is the first option not selected on initial view, any ideas? I have updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/AqRET/1/

Comment: What you do is setting a reference to a self.options()[i].name property of the object. Instead you need to disconnect them and to set the first value of self.selectedPaymentOption as optionNames[0]().toString() (string representation of name property of options object) http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/AqRET/3/